# Rest API with Spring Data MongoDB - Repository method not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, repository, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I am reading and learning Spring Boot data with MongoDB. I have about 10 records in my database in the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5910c7fed6df5322243c36cd"),
    name: "car"
}
```

When I open the url:

```
http://localhost:8090/items
```

I get an exhaustive list of all items.  However, I want to use the methods of `MongoRepository` such as `findById`, `count` etc.  When I use them as such:

```
http://localhost:8090/items/count
http://localhost:8090/items/findById/5910c7fed6df5322243c36cd
http://localhost:8090/items/findById?id=5910c7fed6df5322243c36cd
```

I get a 404.

My setup is as so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Document
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4343106526681673638L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "item", path = "items")
public interface ItemRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<Item, String>, ItemRepositoryCustom {

}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to implement the methods as defined by `MongoRepository` or will they be automatically implemented?  I am lost and have been trying to figure this out for so long.  I do not have any methods in my controller, its empty.

Comment: Have you looked at the request mappings that are looked when you application starts? It will show you all of the mappings that are automatically created by Spring Data REST.

Comment: Excuse the typos. That should have said “that are logged when your application starts”

Comment: Thank you Andy.  Is there a feature in Eclipse that can tell us all the mappings?  Sorry, I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the findById method in order for it to be exposed.

```
Item findById(String id);
Item findByName(String name);
```

Note that you don't need to implement the methods. SpringBoot will analyse the method name and provide the proper implementation

Comment: it works.  However, the count method does not work this way. Is it because the return type is long instead of Long?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue,

After removing `@Configuration,@ComponentScan` everything worked fine.